# Where to put partials shared by the whole application in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, partials

Where would I go about placing partial files shared by more than one model?
I have a page called `crop.html.erb` that is used for one model - `Photo`.
Now I would like to use it for another model called `User` as well.

I *could* copy and paste the code but that's not very DRY, so I figured I would move it into a partial.

Since it's shared between two models - *where would I place that partial*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Rails convention is to put shared partials in `/app/views/shared`.

Comment: partials in /app/views/shared/ are not being picked up in my Rails 4 app for some reason?!?

Comment: Not any more, for rails 4, the right directory is app/views/application, and I think it makes sense...

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/directory-for-shared-partials-in-rails

Comment: "This makes `app/views/application/` a great place for your shared partials" - [Rails Guide Layouts & Rendering](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 54):

**Update**

Layout inheritance is now in the guides under [layout and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#layout-inheritance)
Template inheritance works similarly.

**Rails 3.1 and following versions** implement template inheritance, so I think the correct place for shared partials is now `/app/views/application/`, say you are in `products#index` you can do the following:

```
-# products#index
= render @products.presence || 'empty'

-# /app/views/application/_empty.html.haml
There are no items
```

btw it's `application` because the connection is the controller inheritance, so this assumes `ProductsController < ApplicationController`

This way if you implement `/app/views/products/_empty.html.haml` that will be taken, the above is a fallback for all the missing partials, and I can't check right now, but I think even for the template itself...

[Railscast: template inheritance!](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance)

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for a while now. Can't believe the guide nor any other online tutorials neglect to mention this.

Comment: I've sent a pr to the guides doc about this, hopefully it'll get some attention sooner or later https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16738

Comment: dhh wrote: It's [app/views/application] a side-effect from this reasonable case: EmployeesController < PeopleController, which will look first for employees/show, then fall back to look for people/show. It was never intended to fall all the way back to look for application/show. That's an unintended side-effect. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9911#issuecomment-15462128

Comment: Interesting.  I like `app/views/application`: it's very consistent, I doubt they'll remove it now.

Answer (score 31):

TL;DR

***Rails 3.1, Rails 4, Rails 5** and whatever comes next*

```
app/views/application
```

The engine searches this path automatically if the view is not found in the controller path.

***Rails 3 and prior***

```
app/views/shared
```

The engine does NOT search this path automatically.

---

Long story

> **Rails 3** (and prior version) have **no default** location for storing shared views.
>
> The *unofficial convention* is to store shared views in **app/views/shared**. Wherever you'd end up storing them though, you have to specify the path

```
# render app/views/shared/menu.html.erb
<%= render :partial => "shared/menu" %>
```

This suggestion was popularized by [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails).

> **Rails 3.1** introduces an **official standard** for where to store shared views:
> **app/views/application**
>
> Thanks to this standard, the engine now automatically looks for templates in *app/views/application*. As a result, **you don't have to use the full path anymore**.
>
> Those curious can follow [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/directory-for-shared-partials-in-rails) the thought process behind this decision.

Old syntax

```
# render app/views/application/menu.html.erb
# unless menu.html.erb is found in appp/views/my_controller
<%= render :partial => "menu" %>
```

New syntax

```
# render app/views/application/menu.html.erb
# unless menu.html.erb is found in appp/views/my_controller
<%= render partial: "menu" %>
```

Of course, you can still place your shared views wherever you want and reference them by path

`<%= render :partial => "my_own_special_shared_folder/menu" %>`

Unless you have a very good reason to do this though, please stick to the new standard and store your shared views in `app/views/application`.

Answer (score 5):

[The Rails View](http://pragprog.com/book/warv/the-rails-view) uses `app/views/layouts` for shared partials like header and footer, but the Ruby on Rails Guide uses `app/views/shared` in [an example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). I guess it comes down to personal preference. I would use `layouts` for high-level stuff like a main nav or a footer, but `shared` for more narrow controller-level stuff like a form.

Answer (score 3):

I general have a *shared* folder in my views that contains commonly used partials.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here in 2021 (rails 6) and got confused by the answers (many different ways).

I asked some senior rails developers what they'd do and they also gave me 2 different answers.

But TL;DR

Create a folder called 'shared' or 'application' inside your `views` folder (e.g. `app/views/shared` or `app/views/application`.

Then simply move the partial there, and access it with either

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/socials' %>

# or

<%= render partial: 'application/socials' %>
```

or even simpler

```
<%= render 'shared/socials' %>

# or

<%= render 'application/socials' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you put them. You can render any partial at any arbitrary location by providing the file's path to `render` - it doesn't need to be associated with the controller that's rendering it. I use a directory simply called `partials` under the `view` directory, and call partials in it like this:

```
render :partial => 'partials/mypartial'
```

Comment: oh I'm well aware. I was interested in the best practice. Thanks, though!

Comment: what is the difference between `render 'partials/mypartial'` and `render partial: 'partials/mypartial` ?